# How to display file structure in intelliJ (after accidentally removing it)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Somewhat new to intelliJ, i can't for the life of me find how to get the file structure in the side bar of intelliJ to return after i accidentally removed it

This is what im looking to get back:
[File structure above the side bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg5xU.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

View | Appearance | Navigation Bar:

[image: Navigation Bar]

Or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (Search Everywhere), type Navigation Bar, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle:

[image: Navigation Bar]

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+Home to activate the Navigation bar.

see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate-with-navigation-bar